# 'Splitting' Identity matrix around others?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say I have some arbitrary matrix, $A$.

$$A=IA=AI$$

where $I$ is the Identity matrix.

If I have another matrix, $B$, which I know to be unitary and invertible, then:

$$A=IA=B^{-1}BA=BB^{-1}A=ABB^{-1}=AB^{-1}B$$

and similarly for $I=BB^*=B^*B$.

But can I also 'split' $I$ expressed in terms of $B$ 'around' $A$?

i.e., is it the case that:

$$IA=BAB^*$$

necessarily?

Or am I mad for even wondering?

Comment: Asking questions is not madness, it is a sign of curiosity :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that unless $A=I$. Because, if say you could, then for a non-diagonal Hermitian matrix $A=U^*DU$ you would get $A=UAU^*=D$ which is clearly not true.

Comment: Thank you. Semi-related - is the inverse of a conjugate transpose the same as the conjugate transpose of the inverse - $A^{*^{-1}} = A^{-1^*}$?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: Oh, yeas, of course it is. Sorry, thanks again.